# PHP with 2 buttons that control relay

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

With my Raspberry PI 3 I am trying to control an dual relay over internet , the Python codes are ok , I tested them and they are working just fine . The problem is the PHP code , I don't have any idea how to make the website . I just want to show 2 buttons , one with Relay ON and one with Relay OFF , I found one on the internet , this is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['LightON']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/relay1on.py");
}
if (isset($_POST['LightOFF']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/relay1off.py");
}
?>

<form method="post">
<button class="btn" name="LightON">Light ON</button>&nbsp;
<button class="btn" name="LightOFF">Light OFF</button><br><br>
</form>


</html>
```

I made a nano with the code (originally it was for switching a light on and off , with relay of course , just edited a bit so it will exec the python that I need when the button is pressed) and put it in /var/www/html/

I get what I should get , but the buttons won't work.I can touch them but the page just refreshes and the relay is doing nothing.
If someone could help me I would apreciate.Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of buttons you should use `input type='radio'` with submit button to get one value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I will try then come back with feedback , thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a php script: light.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['light']) && $_POST['light'] == "on")
  {
    exec("sudo python /home/pi/relay1on.py");
    echo "Light on!";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['light']) && $_POST['light'] == "off")
  {
    exec("sudo python /home/pi/relay1off.py");
    echo "Light off!";
  }
?>
```

This is the index.html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btnLightON" class="btn">Light ON</button>
    <button id="btnLightOFF" class="btn">Light OFF</button>

    <script>
      var buttonLightON = document.getElementById("btnLightON");
      var buttonLightOFF = document.getElementById("btnLightOFF");

      buttonLightON.onclick = function()
      {
        Light(true);
      }
      buttonLightOFF.onclick = function()
      {
        Light(false);
      }


      function Light(b)
      {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "light.php";
        var params = "";
        if(b == true)
        {
          params = "light=on"
        }
        else if(b == false)
        {
          params = "light=off"
        }
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                console.log(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I made it with XMLHttpRequests, so it would execute the php code without the reloading the page.
In the case of Light ON button, it sends a POST request to light.php with parameter light=on, and in the case of the other button, same thing except parameter light=off.
The php code will execute the proper python script for each case and write a message, you can see in the console.